# Hide golang messages

Tags: go, flags, message

Is it possible to hide the golang messages? I show you an example:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var signal = flag.String("z", "", "")

func main() {

    flag.Usage = func() {
        fmt.Printf("Usage: kata -z <command>\n\n")
        fmt.Printf("    test\tTesting\n")
        fmt.Printf("    version\tVersion\n")
        fmt.Println("")
    }

    flag.Parse()
    if len(os.Args) != 3 {
        flag.Usage()
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    switch *signal {
    case "test":
        fmt.Println("testing...")
    case "version":
        fmt.Println("0.0.1")
    default:
        fmt.Println("incorrect...")
    }
}
```

This app show to user the next information:
https://play.golang.org/p/oYwADdmlAJ

But if I write in the command-line `kata -flag`, the system returns: `flag needs an argument:` or `flag provided but not defined:` and the information that I show you before.

I would like to know if it's possible to hide the golang messages?

P.S.: If you don't understand my question, I can rephrase.

Comment: What exactly do you want to hide? The flag package is doing precisely what you tell it to.

Comment: I think this is referring to the error messages output during the course of `flag.Parse()`.

Comment: I want to hide the messages that golang returns me: `flag needs an argument:` or  `flag provided but not defined:` and to show only the flag.Usage function

Comment: Thanks @Adrian! I'm going to write a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the global functions in `flag` actually passes through to a global `flag.FlagSet` called `flag.CommandLine`. Internally, this prints errors to an output, which is stderr by default. You can suppress the messages by setting this explicitly to, for example, `ioutil.Discard`:

```
flag.CommandLine.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)
flag.Parse()
```

This will discard all messages output internally by `flag.Parse()`. You could also log it to anywhere else you choose by passing in an appropriate `io.Writer`.

Comment: I am facing the same question regarding preventing output from the flag package. When I try you solution I get the following error: ```undefined: ioutil```.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't add an import for `ioutil`: https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

Before:

```
flag.Parse()
if len(os.Args) != 3 {
    flag.Usage()
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Now:

```
if len(os.Args) != 3 || os.Args[1] != "-z" {
    flag.Usage()
    os.Exit(1)
} else {
    flag.Parse()
}
```

Comment: This will fix your specific error case, but it may still output its own messages in some cases. See my answer for a comprehensive solution.